# Where is the entry point of a netbeans plugin?

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins

I made a plugin in netbeans and I have a class which is actually an abstract action. I think this is the action which connects the ui of the plugin, but it's not that point which I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of entry points of a NetBeans Plugin, it depends what your plugin does, you could

- Add an action at some point of the UI
- Add a cookie (node action)
- Adding a file type, so you could open a self-implemented editor
- Include a ModuleInstall (similar to a BundleActivator in OSGi), so it would do something when NetBeans starts up
- Implement your own project type
- Register some other services that are provided by other plugins

You should provide a lot more information, if you want a specific answer.

Comment: Well, I try, but it's a brand new situation for me. Only thing I found is a tutorial for netbeans plugin, but there's only the action class. I mean I want to start a local server at the plugin starts to run. Unfortunately I can only do it in the action atm, which is a huge antipattern.

Comment: So then you might have a look at "New File" -> "Module Development" -> "Installer / Activator". This will create a class which extends from org.openide.modules.ModuleInstall, there you will have to overwrite the method restored(). This isn't recommended, because in 99% it is a bad idea to start something just because the user startet the application, you should ask yourself: Do you really need to start your server when the application starts? Maybe it is enough to start it when the user really needs it (e.g. when clicking an action). Hope this helps.